# Where can I find a Text-to-Speech component for delphi?

Tags: delphi, components, text-to-speech

I want to add text to speech user guided instruction to my applications. Where can I find a Text to speech component to do that. I do not want to use the Windows functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chant SpeechKit has everithing you need
http://www.chant.net/Products/SpeechKit/Default.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I read the Brian Long articles

http://www.blong.com/Conferences/DCon2002/Speech/Speech.htm
http://www.blong.com/Conferences/DCon2002/Speech/SAPI51/SAPI51.htm

And wrote my own. I use this all day long to read newsgroups, emails and articles.

Comment: Very interesting, although mm2010 indicated he didn't want to use Windows functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a Delphi component that 'wraps' the Windows speech API, you could try this:

http://www.o2a.com/dtalk.htm

However, if you want a complete speech synthesizer which is totally independent of the Windows system, that's a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions after a wander thru the web:

- [MBROLA Inside...](http://tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola/mbrtts.html)
- [AkaSig - Free Text-to-speech technologies](http://www.akasig.org/2004/08/05/free-text-to-speech-technologies/)
- [TextAloud](http://www.nextup.com/index.html?source=GA&campaign=TTS&Adgroup=tts&ad=011&gclid=CI-x7MPwkpcCFQhJagodaAMq-w)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.nuance.com/dragon/index.htm   is a private API helps us to recognize speech and convert text to speech